# one array in two .php files, array is unrecognized in File No. 2

Tags: php, xampp, dreamweaver

I have two .php files in the same folder on my computer.  The first file is called "Client Instructions.php" and the second file is called "form_data_checker.php".

In the "Client Instructions.php" file, I have this snippet of code:

```
$required = array('name', 'comments');
require 'form_data_checker.php';
```

In the "form_data_checker.php" file, I have this code:

```
if(empty($temp) && in_array($key, $required)){ // etc.}
```

I'm using DreamWeaver and it looks like my "require" statement is correctly combining the two files.  However, when I run my program I get error messages that the $required variable is not recognized as an array.

Can someone help me figure out why my $required array is not being recognized in my code in the "form_data_checker.php" file?

Here is the exact error message I'm getting:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: expected in C:\xampp\htdocs\introducingphp\form_data_checker.php on line 16

Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\introducingphp\form_data_checker.php on line 16
```

Thanks!

Ok, I'm including the entire contents of the two files because I'd really like to get this solved.  Here is "Client Instructions.php":

```
<?php
require './includes/form_data_checker.php'; 
$myErrors = array();
$somethingsMissing = array();
$expectedInfo = array();
$requiredInfo = array();

if (isset($_POST['send'])){
    $to = 'test@test.com';
    $subject = 'Feedback from Client Information form';
    $expectedInfo = array('name', 'email', 'comments');
    $requiredInfo = array('name', 'comments');
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Client Contact Information</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Client Information</h1>
<?php if ($myErrors || $somethingsMissing) { ?>
<p class="warning"> Please fix the item(s) indicated. </p>
<?php } ?>
<form name="contact" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <p>
        <label for="name"> Name:
        <?php if ($somethingsMissing && in_array('name', $somethingsMissing)) { ?>
        <span class="warning"> Please enter your name </span>
        <?php } ?>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for"email"> Email (optional):
                <?php if ($somethingsMissing && in_array('email', $somethingsMissing)) { ?>
        <span class="warning"> Please enter your email </span>
                <?php } ?>
        </label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
    <p>
        <label for="address"> Address:
                <?php if ($somethingsMissing && in_array('address', $somethingsMissing)) { ?>
        <span class="warning"> Please enter your address </span>
                <?php } ?>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="address" id="address">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Submit Information">
    </p>
<form>
<pre>
<?php

if($_GET){
    echo 'Contents of the $_GET array: <br>';
    print_r($_GET);
} elseif ($_POST) {
    echo 'Contents of the $_POST array: <br>';
    print_r($_POST);
}
?>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is "form_data_checker.php":

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST as $formFieldKeyName => $clientEnteredDataItem){
    $tempClientData = is_array($clientEnteredDataItem) ? $clientEnteredDataItem : trim($clientEnteredDataItem);

    if(empty($tempClientData) && in_array($formFieldKeyName, $requiredInfo)){
        $somethingsMissing[]=$formFieldKeyName;
        $$formFieldKeyName='';
    } else if(in_array($formFieldKeyName, $expectedInfo)){
        $$formFieldKeyName = $tempClientData;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is this `if(empty($temp) && in_array($key, $required)){ }` in a function? if so, try `$GLOBALS['required']` in place of `$required`

Comment: One issue is that my code as far as I can tell is exactly the same as the tutorial I am working on.  The instructor wasn't using GLOBALS and his files worked together perfectly.  However, I will play around with Globals and see what I can do with it.

Comment: As someone already suggested, ensure you are not redefining the `$required` variable in `'form_data_checker.php'`

Comment: The line of code in question is the first time I use that variable in that file.  Also, this same error appears for the other array variable I am trying to carry over from "Client Instructions.php" for use in the "for_data_checker.php" file.  Very strange.  Maybe I should start over and simply ask "how does one use one array variable between two .php files?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```
require './includes/form_data_checker.php';
```

is the first line, which is called before you actually declare `$requiredInfo`, so to ensure that the file is called after the array is declared, I moved the `require` statement. I think this should solve the issue.

```
<?php

$myErrors = array();
$somethingsMissing = array();
$expectedInfo = array();
$requiredInfo = array();

if (isset($_POST['send'])){
    $to = 'test@test.com';
    $subject = 'Feedback from Client Information form';
    $expectedInfo = array('name', 'email', 'comments');
    $requiredInfo = array('name', 'comments');
}

require './includes/form_data_checker.php'; 
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Client Contact Information</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Client Information</h1>
<?php if ($myErrors || $somethingsMissing) { ?>
<p class="warning"> Please fix the item(s) indicated. </p>
<?php } ?>
<form name="contact" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <p>
        <label for="name"> Name:
        <?php if ($somethingsMissing && in_array('name', $somethingsMissing)) { ?>
        <span class="warning"> Please enter your name </span>
        <?php } ?>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for"email"> Email (optional):
                <?php if ($somethingsMissing && in_array('email', $somethingsMissing)) { ?>
        <span class="warning"> Please enter your email </span>
                <?php } ?>
        </label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
    <p>
        <label for="address"> Address:
                <?php if ($somethingsMissing && in_array('address', $somethingsMissing)) { ?>
        <span class="warning"> Please enter your address </span>
                <?php } ?>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="address" id="address">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Submit Information">
    </p>
<form>
<pre>
<?php

if($_GET){
    echo 'Contents of the $_GET array: <br>';
    print_r($_GET);
} elseif ($_POST) {
    echo 'Contents of the $_POST array: <br>';
    print_r($_POST);
}
?>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: THANK YOU thank you THANK YOU.  It was driving me crazy.  Strange thing is, is that I swear I had moved that up earlier to no avail.  However, I didn't realize it did make a difference where the "require" statement is placed.  THANKS so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `global`:

```
global $required;
if(empty($temp) && in_array($key, $required)){ // etc.}
```

Comment: Good idea, but that didn't seem to change anything.  I'm editing my question to include the exact error message I'm receiving if that helps anyone answer my question.

Comment: Do you try to use `global`?

Comment: Maybe in the "form_data_checker.php" file you redefine the `$required`  variable?

Comment: I will try that.  One issue is I'm trying to follow the code in the tutorial, and as far as I can tell my code is exactly the same as his, yet it's not recognizing the variables from File No. 1 in File No. 2

Answer (score 1):

its not necessary to use globals. it should work even without it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_GLOBALS['required'] = array('name', 'comments');
require 'form_data_checker.php';

//form_data_checker.php
if(empty($temp) && in_array($key, $_GLOBALS['required'])){ // etc.}
```

The above method can also work. However, it's not good practice. Use $_SESSION[] variables instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are including the "form_data_checker.php" file before you are defining `$requiredInfo`. Since `$requiredInfo` is not defined yet it results in the warning that parameter 2 is not an array.

Update "Client Instructions.php" so that "form_data_checker.php" is executed after you define and populate the `$requiredInfo` array.

"Client Instructions.php" should look like this after the change:

```
<?php
$myErrors = array();
$somethingsMissing = array();
$expectedInfo = array();
$requiredInfo = array();

if (isset($_POST['send'])){
    $to = 'test@test.com';
    $subject = 'Feedback from Client Information form';
    $expectedInfo = array('name', 'email', 'comments');
    $requiredInfo = array('name', 'comments');
}

// now when 'form_data_checker.php' is called, $requiredInfo will be defined
require './includes/form_data_checker.php'; 
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
....
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but one problem with that is that I actually have several variables that all should be read between the two files.  I'm copying my code word for word from a tutorial that is working for the teacher, so I'm really confused why mine isn't working.